# Pull Back (change of variables)

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let be $h:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ a change of variables (diffeomorphism). Let be $X$ a vector fields in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continuous application. Define
$(Xf):\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $(Xf)=<X,\nabla f>$. Being $h$ a change of variables, $h_{*}X=\widetilde{X}$ where
$$
(h_{*}X)(p)=Dh(h^{-1}(p))X(h^{-1}(p))
$$
and $Dh$ denotes the differential of $h$. Given a function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $h_{*}f=f\circ h^{-1}$.
Is that true 
$$
h_{*}(Xf)(\widetilde{p})=h_{*}Xh_{*}f(\widetilde{p})
$$
where $\widetilde{p}=h(p)$?